# Replace method on Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,2,6,7,2,8,9,2,10]
```

I want to replace all the `2`s with `'x'` and can't do this. I tried:

- 1st attempt: `array.select{|num| num == 2? num = 'x' : num}`
- 2nd attempt: `array.select{|num| num == 2}.replace(['x'])`

I'm making this harder than it is.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it was to replace all the 2s in the array with 'x'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,2,6,7,2,8,9,2,10]

array.map!{ |e| e == 2 ? 'x' : e }
array # => [1, "x", 3, 4, 5, "x", 6, 7, "x", 8, 9, "x", 10]
```

`map!` changes `array`, but if you don't want to change the array itself:

```
foo = array.map{ |e| e == 2 ? 'x' : e }
array # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 8, 9, 2, 10]
foo # => [1, "x", 3, 4, 5, "x", 6, 7, "x", 8, 9, "x", 10]
```

Comment: man, i feel like an idiot...
thanks Tin Man! I still have 9 minutes on the accept...

Comment: Personally, I prefer a conditional expression over the conditional operator: `array.map {|e| if e == 2 then 'x' else e end }`